Is it acceptable to apply Principal Component Analysis and K-means clustering to mixed numerical and dummy data?
I have a dataset with numerical (continuous and discrete) as well as categorical variables which I transformed into dummy (n-1) variables. I performed PCA to this data and then K-means clustering to the PCA-transformed data to group the individuals/observations with similar characteristics using R. But I'm having doubts on this as K-means clustering works by determining the mean of the observations in a cluster after grouping them initially with randomly placed cluster centers, and then does this iteratively. It somehow doesn't make sense to me to use the means of dummy variables as some of them are just one categorical variable. I also want to know if I should remove the rows/observations that are similar across variables and if it has some influence on the accuracy of PCA if I choose to do otherwise.
Maybe it would be more appropriate to perform alternative methods like Factorial Analysis of Mixed Data instead of PCA, and then use something equivalent of K-means clustering but applicable for mixed datasets. Hoping somebody could help me with this. Thanks!
